# Why this read clipboard code doesn't work immediatly after restart?

Tags: android, clipboard, clipboardmanager

This is my code:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
if(clip!=null) {
    ClipData.Item item = clip.getItemAt(0);
    String text= item.getText().toString();
    Log.d("log_tag", "clipboard: "+text);
}
else {
    Log.d("log_tag", "clipboard empty");
}
```

The problem is, after restarting device, this code says "clipboard empty", even though there is some text in clipboard (And I can verify that by pasting it in other android programs). Then, when I copy something new into android clipboard, my code can see it again and the problem disappears completely!

What can be the reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: In which activity method you have written the coding for clip board?

Comment: Originally it is in a non-GUI thread but i run it via runOnUiThread. And I also tested this code directly in the main activity with the same results.